# PHP exec() clear output

Tags: php, arrays, output, exec

I have a PHP file (file.php) with the following code:

```
<?php
exec("program.exe command",$output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

When file.php is opened in browser it prints the following output:

```
"Array ( [0] => my_output ) "
```

I just want "my_output" to be printed. Not the "`Array ([0] =>`" part. How to do it?

Comment: `print_r` is for printing array thats why you are getting that output. use `echo($output[0])` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
// Correct
print $arr['fruit'];  // apple
print $arr['veggie']; // carrot

print $arr['fruit'];  // apple
```

Try with this code:

```
<?php
exec("program.exe command",$output);
echo $output[0];
?>
```

Read more about arrays in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php